# How to return null to a user defined class in c++

Tags: c++, null

I have defined a Queue class that works with a Card class that I have also created, the function method return is supposed to return the Card when called, but if there is no card it should return null. The problem with this is that I keep getting errors when I try `null`, `NULL`, and `'\0'`.

For `'\0'` I get a char to Card error, for `NULL` I get a long to Card error, the strange part is that null is not recognized as a keyword and is ignored.

I am now wondering if I have to define null in the Cards class somehow, or if its a different issue altogether. Here's the code I am using for the Queue class, in case you needed:

```
class Queue{
    Card cards[52];
    int first;
    int last;
    int count;

public:
    Queue();

    void insert(Card insert);
    Card remove();
    int getSize();
};

Queue::Queue(){
    first = last = count = 0;
}

Card Queue::remove(){
    if(count == 0)
        return null;
    Card temp = cards[last];
    last++;
    count--;
    if (last > 0)
        last = 51;
    return temp;
}
```

EDIT:

```
class Queue{
    Card *cards;
}
Queue::Queue(){
    cards = new Card[52];
}
Card Queue::remove(){
    if(count == 0)
        return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The functions needs to return a `card` and `null` isn't a `Card` (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: Throw an exception or use `boost::optional`.

Comment: Alternatively, change the type to `Card*` and return `nullptr` when `count == 0`.

Comment: This is a hw assignment, and im not supposed to use external classes or much programming outside of what I was given, which said to use a null. I changed the array to Card* the edit is above, but Im still get a conversion from nullptr.